# How to have ReSharper like syntax highlighting without ReSharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, syntax-highlighting, color-scheme

How do I change the color of my properties and methods to be like those with the **ReSharper** plugin? I can't find option in *Visual Studio > Options > Font and Colors* to change these.

[image: Syntax highlighting with ReSharper]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't change the default C# property and method highlighting normally. You can do it by installing an extension though. I recommend you to download and install **[SemanticColorizer by Andreas Reischuck](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndreasReischuck.SemanticColorizer)**.

After installing go to *Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors*. In the drop-down select the `TextEditor` and under display items look for the ones that start with "*Semantic*". Customize these to your desirable color scheme.

If you specifically want the **ReSharper** syntax highlighting, set the "*Semantic Property*" `RGB: (237, 124, 201)` and "*Semantic Normal Method*" `RGB: (0, 234, 234)`. Voilà! You have your ReSharper look and feel.

---

Also thanks to **[AlexK.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246342/alex-k)** for mentioning **[CoCo by George Aleksandria](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GeorgeAleksandria.CoCo-19226)** and **[Visafora](https://viasfora.com/#features)**. You can use these extensions as well to achieve the same result.

Comment: https://github.com/GeorgeAlexandria/CoCo & https://viasfora.com are two other good colorize extensions

Comment: @AlexK. thanks for pitching in! I will add those to my answer as well.

Comment: changing these settings alone does not result in exact look of resharper colors. I'm not a big fan of resharper but I really like their coloring. Have you found any complete list of settings?

Comment: Amazing. Thanks Busko. this worked for me perfectly.

Comment: @CageE - if you combine those settings with the example settings file (https://github.com/hicknhack-software/semantic-colorizer/files/763058/arBmind_InputMono_Viasfora_SemanticColorizer_Dark.zip) linked from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndreasReischuck.SemanticColorizer, you should get pretty close to the Resharper colours.